# Angularjs: How to create a optional route map param?

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angularjs-routing

On AngularJS 1.1.5, I've got two mapped routes in the form:

```
 /category/:name/:article 
 
 /category/:name
```

I'd like to only have the latest, and route the param :article to a action. This action is actually expanding an element in a list, so I don't need to reload the controller, etc or let's imagine in other circumstance could be for example running an animation. For example, let's say I had a slideshow and I wanted to show the slide number 5 - this sort of thing! No need to reload everything!

The routes (I'm using the slider example as it's less confusing):

```
.config(function(...))

$routePRovider
.when('/slider/:category', {
    templateUrl: 'slider.html',
    controller: 'sliderCtrl'
})

.when('/slider/:category/:number', {
    templateUrl: 'slider.html',
    controller: 'sliderCtrl'
});
```

Then on .run() or .controller(),

```
scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current){

        var path = $location.path();


        if((path.match("\/slider\/(.+)\/(.+)"))){ ... }; /* I'd like the 2 param to be optional, I'm still trying to find the right or correct regex for this atm. I knnow that I'll have to keep just one routemap controller, the one without the :number param */

})
```

After some research I found a possible solution:

The pattern

```
"/foo/bar/das".match("\/foo\/([^\/]+)(\/[^\/]+)?")
```

returns the three params and only two if the last omitted, but I get the extra "/", as in ["foo", "bar", "/das"] and ["foo", "bar", undefined]. I'm fine having to deal with the extra "/" though!

This one is working nicely:

```
"/foo/bar".match("\/foo\/([^\/]+)(?:\/([^\/]+))?")
```

### Important note

After some testing and finding the pattern, at the moment it looks like AngularJS 1.15 $routeProvider doesn't really support it? I've posted this, thinking that, by keeping only one routeMapper for /foo/:bar/:das where third param is optional could work as /foo/:bar and then using regex on locationChange().

Answer (score 0):

To make both params optional you can use:

```
var m = path.match(/issue(?:\/([^/]*))?(?:\/([^/]*))?/i);
```

Comment: Thanks for looking @anybhava I'll test your pattern :) Just made a change on a typo I had changed "issue" to "slider" or "foo" thanks :D

Comment: Sure you can use: `path.match(/slider(?:\/([^/]*))?(?:\/([^/]*))?/i);`